# terraform destroy error - aws_security_group: DependencyViolation: resource sg-XXX has a dependent object

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Following Terraform script always returns following error when destroying the infrastructure. Notice that security group "GC-SG-VPC1" is being used in ingress rule in security group "default". During destroy Terraform attempts to delete "GC-SG-VPC1" and fails after multiple retries.

Any suggestions to get around this is much appreciated.

**aws_security_group: DependencyViolation: resource sg-XXX has a dependent object**

```
# Security Group GC-SG-VPC1
resource "aws_security_group" "GC-SG-VPC1" {
  name   = "GC-SG-VPC1"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc1.id

  tags = {
    Name = "GCTF-SG-VPC1"
  }
  #SSH and all PING
  ingress {
    description = "Allow SSH"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow all PING"
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow iPERF3"
    from_port   = 5201
    to_port     = 5201
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

# Security Group default
resource "aws_default_security_group" "default" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc1.id

  ingress {
    description = "Default SG for VPC1"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    self        = true
  }

  ingress {
    description     = "Include EC2 SG in VPC1 default SG"
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.GC-SG-VPC1.id]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Default VPC1-SG"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **shouldn't be using** `aws_default_security_group`, as this is in most cases not needed and considered as an advance feature. Default SG can't be deleted, nor TF deletes it rules, as explained in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/default_security_group):

> All ingress or egress rules will be left as they are at the time of removal.

Since you bound your `GC-SG-VPC1` with `aws_default_security_group`, you have to go to AWS console and **manually remove** this relationship, as TF does not do it.

Then, instead of `aws_default_security_group` use just regular `aws_security_group`.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. This definitely makes sense, will try it out this morning.